# How to sort by ISO week and begin with today's week number

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to query data from oracle and sort it by week, but the result is begin with week 52 and now is week 44 actually.
this is my sql :

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT
        to_char(contract.MIGRATION_SUCCESS_DATE,'yyyy-iw') metric,
        sum(contract.BLIS_MRR)                    mrr,
        count(contract.CONTRACT_ID)               count
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
              CONTRACT_ID,
              BLIS_MRR,
              MIGRATION_SUCCESS_DATE
            FROM MR_MIGRATION_SITE) contract WHERE MIGRATION_SUCCESS_DATE < sysdate
      GROUP BY to_char(contract.MIGRATION_SUCCESS_DATE,'yyyy-iw'))
ORDER BY metric DESC;
```

and the following picture is result:
[image]

Comment: "WHERE MIGRATION_SUCCESS_DATE < sysdate"  this sentence is just for test

Comment: Please post result as text, not as screen shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to use format `to_char(contract.MIGRATION_SUCCESS_DATE,'iyyy-iw')`

The year of ISO week can be different to actual year, for example January 1st 2017 was week 52 of 2016, i.e. `2016-W52` according ISO definition!

I recommend format `'iyyy-"W"iw'` which is compliant to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

And perhaps change your GROUP BY clause to `GROUP BY TRUNC(contract.MIGRATION_SUCCESS_DATE,'iw')`

Comment: The combined (best) solution is:
`to_char(contract.MIGRATION_SUCCESS_DATE, 'iyyy-"W"iw')` Thanks @Wernfried

Answer (score 0):

You get the problem when the date and the Monday of that date's week are in different years.

To fix it you can use [@Wernfried Domscheit's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47012574/1509264) and the `iyyy-iw` format to get the ISO year and week:

```
TO_CHAR( contract.MIGRATION_SUCCESS_DATE, 'IYYY-IW' )
```

**Initial (Incorrect) Solution**:

<s>To fix it you can truncate the date to the start of the ISO week and then convert it to `yyyy-iw` format</s>:

```
TO_CHAR(
  TRUNC( contract.MIGRATION_SUCCESS_DATE, 'IW' )
  'yyyy-iw'
)
```

For example:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/504e5/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data( dt ) AS
SELECT DATE '2016-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2014-12-31' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT dt,
       TO_CHAR( dt, 'iyyy-iw' ) AS trunc_iw,
       TO_CHAR( TRUNC( dt, 'IW' ), 'yyyy-iw' ) AS trunc_iw2,
       TO_CHAR( dt, 'yyyy-iw' ) AS non_trunc_iw
FROM   test_data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/504e5/2/0)**:

```
|                   DT | TRUNC_IW | TRUNC_IW2 | NON_TRUNC_IW |
|----------------------|----------|-----------|--------------|
| 2016-12-31T00:00:00Z |  2016-52 |   2016-52 |      2016-52 |
| 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z |  2016-52 |   2016-52 |      2017-52 |
| 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z |  2017-01 |   2017-01 |      2017-01 |
| 2014-12-31T00:00:00Z |  2015-01 |   2014-01 |      2014-01 | -- initial version is incorrect for this date
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer solves my question perfectly. 
Thank you once again!!!

Comment: The solution does not work for `2014-12-31`, for example. `2014-12-31` is week 1 of 2015 but this query returns `2014-01`.

Comment: @KDFinal Please accept WernfriedDomscheit's answer - it should be the correct one.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for the edge case, updated so the (currently) accepted answer is correct but yours should be the accepted answer instead.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  Thank you and i have change the acception to your answer,  i'm not fully consider the possible conditions.